# Switch Netapp expansion FC port from target to initiator

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, fibre-channel, netapp

I have a v3200 with a 4 port FC expansion card. I am trying to switch one (or all, doesn't matter) of those ports from target to initiator. When I execute fcadmin config, I get:

```
                  Local
Adapter Type      State                  Status
---------------------------------------------------
0c   target     CONFIGURED             online
0d   target     CONFIGURED             online
```

Those are only the onboard ports, and I can't find a way to make it show me the ports on the card (4a, 4b, 4c, and 4d). I'm running 8.0 in 7 mode, and the manual [claims](http://netappsky.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/fc_iscsi_config_guide_80.pdf) (page 22) to support a combination of initiator and target ports on my card.

edit: here is what happens when I try.

```
nas> fcadmin config -t initiator 4b
Error: adapter 4b is not configurable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [THIS](http://hd.kvsconsulting.us/netappdoc/801docs/html/ontap/bsag/GUID-9657E3AB-3ACA-4717-B049-F4EA8611CF2E.html), "If you are installing target expansion adapters, or if you exceed the allowed number of adapter ports, you must set the onboard adapters to unconfigured before installing the expansion adapters". I know this is for targets but I'm slightly worried it may apply for initiators too.

EDIT - this is cheating a bit but never mind.

If you do a 'sysconfig -ca' it'll list the cards inside the machine, in your case we get 'sysconfig: slot 4 OK: X2054A: QLogic ISP 2432; PCI-E quad-port Fibre Channel (QLE2464)' and that particular card cannot be 'switched' from one mode to another. It's a bit poor from a NetApp perspective if you ask me, it's just an FC port after all, but they do make quite a lot of profit from this sort of thing so there you go.

Comment: I am starting to suspect that the card is hard-coded to be a target. Do you know of a way to check that?

Comment: My NetApp guys aren't around now (8pm here) but I have a horrid feeling only the internal ports can be initiators - which would be nasty... I'll ask them on Monday.

Comment: Been doing more digging. The fcadmin command should work but the card MUST be offline first. If the ‘fcadmin –d adapter_name’ command won’t take it offline then you can sometimes force it offline by un-plugging the cable, alternatively you can change it with the filer in maintenance mode.
Oh and the cards that support dual-modes are X2053A, X2055A, SP-2053A andSP-2055A.